# How to scroll page to certain height in angular6

Tags: angular

I'm trying to scroll the page using

```
    ngOnInit(){
        this.innerContent.nativeElement.scrollTop = 290;
       }
```

but the page is not being scrolled.

Comment: you can use ngx-scroll-to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to. i can give an example if u want

Comment: Thanks for the support @Asanka. Will try implementing the plugin .

Comment: If u want i can give an example.

Comment: Hi Asanka, you answer work fine . But and another implementation in the same . 
I will explain you my requirement early:
I have a button in modal page. When I click this button modal has to close and page has to scroll to fixed offset irrespective initial page position

Comment: Can you open a stackblitz.with sample. I can edit as yu want?

Comment: Thanks for your support Asanka. As of now, I handled it by scrolling the window by using "window.scrollTo(0,0)" .
If that isn't a good practise please let me know so that I will share code in stackblitz.

Comment: It idepends. I can't exactly say what is the best, because all are implemented and we are using.I think following documentations well is the thing that we can do.so what do you mean by model in previous, Is that a popup? that was I asked. :)

Comment: yes . its a popup

Comment: I need a sample of project for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ngx-scroll-to npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to to implement that.this is an example project [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-kugax8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)